# selenium RC in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, selenium, nunit, selenium-rc

I'm trying to get a selenium RC 'project' set up in visual studio (2010).  I've been following the instructions, here - http://bonniepan02.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/how-to-use-the-selenium-rc-to-test-your-first-web-application-in-windows/ - but when I attempt to open the project in NUnit, I get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

For further information use the exception Details menu item.
```

This seems odd, as nunit.framework is clearly listed as one of the references.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The key statement is "or one of its dependencies".  You can use .NET Reflector or something like it to see what nunit.framework requires that you're missing.  The NUnit 2.0 version, however, only requires mscorlib.dll 2.0.0.0 and System.dll 2.0.0.0, both of which I'm sure you've got.